# Excel "thinks" a cell has a value but I cannot see value anywhere

Tags: excel

I am trying to loop through a range of cells and send the text of any cells that are not equal to "--" to another procedure for processing.  However, when I loop through the range, there are cells that appear to contain "--", and thus should not be sent to the other routine, but somehow, there are words I cannot see in those cells that are being sent to the other routine.  Been on this for about an hour and 15 minutes, and can't think of anything.

Tried using google to solve, tried changing the format of the cells in the range I am looping through.  In the code below, I have a Testoptions routine that is just to see how the 'AddOptionButtons' routine works.

```
Sub Testoptions()
AddOptionButtons 1, 2, 146
End Sub

Sub AddOptionButtons(col As Integer, frow As Integer, lrow As Integer)
'this routine is meant to add option buttons by knowing the current level prior to the button being clicked (col), and the first and last row to utilize for deciding what buttons to add
Dim captions() As String 'this is going to be utilized to store option button captions prior to adding them
Dim i As Integer 'general counting variable to loop through arrays



ReDim captions(1) 'by default put one element in the array

'call the routine that makes unique arrays by looping through all the levels
For i = frow To lrow

    If USMLE.Cells(col + 1, i) <> "--" Then
    CreateUniqueArray USMLE.Cells(col + 1, i), captions
    End If
Next

'now loop through the array just created
For i = 1 To UBound(captions) - 1
MsgBox (captions(i))

Next



End Sub
```

So what is happening is when I get to some cells that in fact are "--" as the value, the routine seems to think the cell is not "--" and then sends the "--" or in some instances even a totally different value I can't see (a word for instance) to the 'CreateUniqueArray' routine.

Comment: could the `--` be a number format for `0`?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer because it was off base. I wrote a test function that successfully only executes code when the cell's value is NOT `--` and it looks like this:

```
Sub main()
    Call test("Sheet1", 1, 1, 10)
End Sub

Sub test(ByVal sheetName As String, col, frow, lrow As Integer)
    With Sheets(sheetName)
        For i = frow To lrow
            If Not (.Cells(i, col).Value = "--") Then
                MsgBox "Good data at row " & i
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I would modify your for loop accordingly:

```
For i = frow To lrow
    If Not (USMLE.Cells(col + 1, i) = "--") Then
        CreateUniqueArray USMLE.Cells(col + 1, i), captions
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Oh my gosh Tom...I figured out my problem.  It's that I'm an idiot!  The entire time, the problem was I had reversed my variables in the cells statement, and I had the row and column reversed.  This meant there really were blank cells.  Thanks for your work on this, and I'm sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: No problem, I am glad you figured it out!